# Sudoku seed generator

Tags: javascript, beginner, sudoku, generator

The code returns a string ready to seed at sites like [sudoku-solutions.com](https://www.sudoku-solutions.com/).

It works great but as I couldn't find other simple examples for my level I hope for some insights on this and ways to correct what is wrong.

```js
let sudoku = [];

function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

function randomNumber() {
 let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
 return num;
}

function randomFiller(a) {
 while (a.length < 9) {
  let num = randomNumber();
  a.push(num);
  if (a.indexOf(num) < a.lastIndexOf(num)) {
   a.pop();
  }
 }
 return a;
}

function populateSudoku() {
 let arr = [];
 while (sudoku.length < 9) {
  arr = [];
  sudoku.push(Array.from(randomFiller(arr)));
 }
 return arr;
}

function arrange3x3() {
 let arr = [];
 let line1 = [];
 let line2 = [];
 let line3 = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
  line1.push(sudoku[i].splice(0, 3));
  line2.push(sudoku[i].splice(0, 3));
  line3.push(sudoku[i].splice(0, 3));
 }
 for (let i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i += 3) {
  sudoku[i].push(line1.splice(0, 3));
 }
 for (let i = 1; i < sudoku.length; i += 3) {
  sudoku[i].push(line2.splice(0, 3));
 }
 for (let i = 2; i < sudoku.length; i += 3) {
  sudoku[i].push(line3.splice(0, 3));
 }
 sudoku = [].concat.apply([], sudoku);
 return sudoku;
}

function shuffleY(lmr) {
 let check = false;
 let x = [];
 let y = [];
 let z = [];
 while (check === false) {
  for (let i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
   x.push(sudoku[i][lmr][0]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
   y.push(sudoku[i][lmr][1]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
   z.push(sudoku[i][lmr][2]);
  }
  if (x.every((element, index) => {
   return index === x.lastIndexOf(element);
  }) && y.every((element, index) => {
   return index === y.lastIndexOf(element);
  })) {
   check = true;
  } else {
   x.splice(0);
   y.splice(0);
   z.splice(0);
   for (let i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
    shuffle(sudoku[i][lmr]);
   }
  }
 }
}

function mirrorSudoku() {
 sudoku.forEach((element, index) => {
  sudoku[index] = [].concat.apply([], element);
 })
 let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sudoku));
 for (let i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < sudoku.length; j++) {
   copy[j][i] = sudoku[i][j];
  }
 }
 for (let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
  sudoku[i].splice(0);
  sudoku[i].push(copy[i].splice(0, 3));
  sudoku[i].push(copy[i].splice(0, 3));
  sudoku[i].push(copy[i].splice(0, 3));
 }
}

populateSudoku();
arrange3x3();
shuffleY(0);
shuffleY(1);
shuffleY(2);
mirrorSudoku();
shuffleY(0);
shuffleY(1);
shuffleY(2);

sudoku = [].concat.apply([], sudoku);
sudoku = [].concat.apply([], sudoku);

console.log(sudoku.join(''));
```